# ICEFaces 1.8 or 2.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I am currently developing an internal application for our company with the following requirements.

- Rich GUI but only basic HTML like components will be used. So component list is not a deciding factor.
- Fuzzy requirements which might change frequently during the implementation stage, and tight turn around times are the norm. Thus am looking for a Drag-&-Drop design

  - The application will rarely be used (max once in a month) and the user base will not exceed 20.
  - Time is a critical factor and thus I do not want to spend time on configuring and troubleshooting the framework. I will go for a easy to integrate solution.

I did a brief research and decided on JSF with IceFaces. But am now confused about the version. If I go with 1.8, I get Drag-&-Drop designing (Netbeans 6.5) but I will be stuck with JSF 1.2

If I choose ICEFaces 2.0 I will have to manually design the UI which might take more time.

Any suggestions on which version to choose?

Comment: You should also check out Grails ( http://www.grails.org/ ). As they say: "Have your next Web 2.0 project done in weeks instead of months. Grails delivers a new age of Java web application productivity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, go with the newest stable version. There are a [lot of reason](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/) to use JSF2.

You can have drag&drop with ICEfaces2 too, at least in Eclipse (see the [wiki](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Creating+ICEfaces+Applications+with+Eclipse)). IDE integration is available for NetBeans, the [release note](http://www.icefaces.org/releasenotes/ICEfaces-2.0.0-Netbeans-6.9-RN.html) mentions a palette (I'm not familiar with NetBeans, but it may be what you're looking for).

Comment: ICEFaces 2 visual editing in eclipse sucks... I tried working with that for 30 mins and I gave up..

Comment: Well, if you need NetBeans drag&drop, go with 1.8.2, it's a stable version too.